# im facing these exceptions but i have created the bean

Tags: spring

[this is the error[this the config file[dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyWP0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtxVm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r81i.png)

[my main file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRYAR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your config.xml path is wrong. You should move the config.xml to "src/main/resources" path.